# While Executing Stored Procedure in MySQL Amazon RDS Show Access Denied

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Error show while executing stored procedure

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Permissions on mysql

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `product`.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `product`.`export_product` TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: What is your stored procedure doing? Can you provide the procedure?

Comment: Fetching Data : - DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE export_product
()
BEGIN
 SET @SQLString = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM product LIMIT 5');
 PREPARE test2 FROM @SQLString;
 EXECUTE test2;
END //
DELIMITER ;

Comment: Dod you try to add the database to the select query?
`SELECT * FROM product.product LIMIT 5`
I'm assuming your table and your database have the same name (`product`).

Comment: yes, i tried with database on select query. but same error shows. SELECT * FROM amy.product LIMIT 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Create DB parameter group](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/).Try the above link to create db parameter group in amazon rds and enable log_bin_trust_function_creators for creating and executing functions triggers and stored procedures